# Extract data from metadata list macro from Confluence's REST API

Tags: confluence, confluence-rest-api

I'm trying to fetch the value of an item in a metadata list on a page in Confluence using the REST API. So far I have been able to extract fetch the body using a URL like this

https://acme.com/rest/api/content/105088446?expand=body.storage 
(documentation here: https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-server-rest-api/expansions-in-the-rest-api)

Or the full contents of the metadata list macro like this
https://acme.com/rest/api/content/105088446/history/10/macro/id/c65d00a3-49e2-40e5-a032-50b6c187d968
(documentation here: https://docs.atlassian.com/confluence/REST/latest/#content)

But neither of these are satisfactory. The first leaves a lot of parsing, the second requires I define the version of the page and even then returns the whole table that needs to be parsed.

Comment: Provided links return an HTTP 404 - Not Found. We cannot understand what you try to perform and how the data is generated for example.

Comment: Yeah they return 404, they are to an imaginary domain called 'acme.com', the point of those links is the form of the url e.g. 'api/content/{content_id}/history/...'. After each of my example urls is a link tot eh documentation that shows how those urls were derived.

Comment: OK, but macro are all different. No API call will return directly a specific part or element of the macro. You will need to parse the body 'storage' or 'view'. It's why I ask you a sample of the response.

Comment: Right, but I can fetch the content of a macro from the a specific version of the page. It would be helpful if I could specify getting the _latest_ version of the page. Since the macro has a guid it seems reasonable to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are referring to the page properties ([Page Properties Macro](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/page-properties-macro-184550024.html)). If so you could try the masterdetails REST service.

```
rest/masterdetail/1.0/detailssummary/lines
```

You can use the [REST API Browser](https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/developer-tools/using-the-rest-api-browser) to discover the parameters (note that this is part of the non-public API, so you need to check of the "Show only public APIs" checkbox to see it in the list).

There is a [similar question](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/38758259/how-to-retrieve-metadata-from-page-properties-using-rest-api) on Atlassian Answers.

Comment: It's not the page properties that I'm fetching, but data writing into he content of the page, usually using the a metadata table.